# How to store a reference to an integer in Swift

Tags: swift, reference-type

I know swift has both reference types and value types.  And I know Int is a value type. But how can I store a reference to an integer?

```
var x:Int = 1
var y:Int = x   // I want y to reference x (not copy)
++y
println(x)     // prints 1, but I want 2
```

I tried using boxed types, and I tried using array of Int, but neither works for holding a reference to integer.

I guess I can write my own

```
class IntRef {
    var a:Int = 0
    init(value:Int) { a = value }
}

var x:IntRef = IntRef(value: 3)
var y = x
++y.a
println(x.a)
```

seems a bit awkward.

Comment: What would be the point of 'storing a reference to an integer'? *Since **integers are immutable** this is not the correct request.* Instead of a 'boxed type' (like Java's Integer, which does *not* affect the mutability) a separate *mutable container*, as shown, can be used.

Comment: (The equivalent in Java to the *mutable container* would be something like [`Holder<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Holder.html), not `Integer`.)

Comment: I guess I should say 'How to store a reference to an integer variable'. I guess it is not obvious to everyone.

Comment: What's the purpose of IntRef? Or, to put it another way, what's wrong with it as a solution? What could you possibly be trying to do that IntRef does not do? Why is it "awkward"? Why isn't it just "the answer" and move on? Classes are reference types, end of story...?

Comment: @JohnHenckel Storing a 'store a reference to an integer' is still not the correct/complete phrasing. One needs a type that can be *mutated*. An integer cannot be; as shown the holder doesn't even store a 'reference'.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've decided to not use references after all. I've just been reading about 'Capturing values with closures' and that seems like a much better alternative. see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no reference type `Integer` or something like that in Swift so you have to make a Box-Type yourself.

For example a generic one:

```
class Reference<T> {
    var value: T
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}
```

Comment: I would probably call it something else to avoid confusion. There is still no 'integer reference' stored, eg.

Comment: @user2864740 I would read it as a `Reference` to `Something`. How would you call it? Maybe `ReferenceTo`?

Comment: Fortunately :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use closures. I think these better because they are more powerful and also more specific. They not only store a reference, but they also indicate how the reference will be used. For example,

```
var x:Int = 1
var setx = { (a:Int) in x = a }
var getx = { x }
setx(getx() + 1)
println(x)             // This will print 2
```

I don't recommend actually defining getx/setx. Define a closure that does a specific task for your application.