# How to get the reference of a value type in Swift?

Tags: swift

Value types such as struct and enum are copied by value. Is it possible to get the reference of variable of value types?

```
struct Test {}

let t = Test()
let s = t  // How to get a reference to t instead of a copy of t?
```

Comment: Why do you need a reference? What's the use-case?

Comment: A very strange question. Value types are those you want to pass by value. If you need a reference, use a reference type.

Comment: @user28434 It could be for porting between languages or for performance. For example, tuple is value type in Swift but reference type in C#.

Comment: In Swift 3 value types are "auto boxed" when cast to `AnyObject`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899111/how-to-store-a-reference-to-an-integer-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR Good stuff - Where can I find info on AnyObject autoboxing behavior?

Comment: [SE-0116](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/545e7bea606f87a7ff4decf656954b0219e037d3/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md): *"Unbridged value types without an obvious Objective-C analog can still be boxed in an instance of an immutable class.  ..."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to get a reference. Kristopher's `Box` solution is one of the most flexible, and can be built as a custom box to handle problems like passing structs to ObjC.

Beyond that, the most obvious is passing `inout` parameters. This isn't precisely the same thing as a reference, but its behavior can be very similar, and definitely can be a part of high-performance code.

And moving down the stack there is `UnsafePointer` and its friends, using `withUnsafePointer(to:)` on general types, or `.withUnsafeBufferPointer` on array types.

But if you need a persistent reference type that can be stored in a property, you'll need a `Box` as Kristopher describes.

(Just to capture it for future readers since I hadn't remembered it, but MartinR pointed it out in a comment: `as AnyObject` can automatically box value types.)

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted Kristopher's answer and yours. Selecting this as the answer for its completeness.

Answer (score 3):

The typical solution is to use a `Box<T>` reference type to wrap the value type. For example:

```
final class Box<T> {
    let value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let t = Test()
let boxed = Box(t)
let anotherReference = boxed
let theValue = anotherReference.value
```

See https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-generics-box/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks, great info!