# Evaluating enums inside defined blocks in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I'm fairly new to Swift (Objective-C for the last 6 years) and I'm having a slight issue when evaluating an Enum value inside a block. The best way to demonstrate is this with an example.

```
enum MyType {
    case type1
    case type2
}

class MySuperClass {
    var type: MyType
    var object: SomeObject

    init(param: SomeObject) {
        self.type = .type1
        self.object = param
    }

    public func doSomething(handler block: @escaping (AnyObject) -> Void) {
        self.type = .type2
        // assign handler block to property, blah blah
        object.execHandler(forMethod: "testing", completion: { (response) -> Void in
            block(response)
        })
    }

    public func reset() {
        self.type = .type1
    }
}

class MySubClass: MySuperClass {

    override init(param: SomeObject) {
        super.init(param: param)

        let myBlock: MyBlockType = { (responseObject) -> Void in
            // do some stuff

            // ISSUE ARISES HERE
            switch self.type {
                case .type2:
                    print("Is type2")
                default:
                    print("Do Nothing")
            }
        };
        object.addHandler(forMethod: "testing", processBlock: myBlock)
    }

}
```

Then when using this, I'm simply doing something like this:

```
let myObject = MySubClass(param: passingInAnObject) // the block is defined and setup (this sets the 'type' to .type2) 
myObject.doSomething(handler: { (responseObject) -> Void in
    print("completed")
})
// do some other stuff
// ...
object.reset()
```

As can be seen, the `doSomething` method will set the enum to `.type2` and run the block, however, when the `myBlock` block is evaluated, the old value is used (`.type1` not `.type2`). Thus, the code execution always falls into the line `print("Do Nothing")`.

I believe that enums are copied by value in Swift, so I have also tried to wrap these in an object as stated in this StackOverflow post ([How to store a reference to an integer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899111/how-to-store-a-reference-to-an-integer-in-swift)), but with no avail.

I would appreciate some advice on how to overcome this, or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You're probably calling `object.reset()` before `myBlock` is executed, assuming it gets called after something is run asynchronously.

Comment: @dan well isn't this embarrassing ... that `object.reset()` should be in the completion handler. Should have really seen that sooner. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It appears, after investigation following Dan's comment, that the enum var was being reset to the original value before the asynchronous block was executed.